# Get a local notification when entering a geolocation

Tags: ios, swift, geolocation, core-location, uilocalnotification

I m trying to get a local notification to fire when entering a geolocation, i followed some online tutorials, and I requesting always access to the location, but i can't get the actual location monitoring to work. I have a GPX file to simulate entering the location. But it never fires didEnterRegion.

Heres the code I have now:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
    if region.identifier == "Sparkle" {
        let notification = UILocalNotification()
        notification.alertBody = "Dont forget to punch in!"
        notification.regionTriggersOnce = false
    }
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
    if region.identifier == "Sparkle" {
        let notification = UILocalNotification()
        notification.alertBody = "Dont forget to punch out!"
        notification.regionTriggersOnce = false

    }
}

func regionWithGeotification() -> CLCircularRegion {
    // 1
    let sparkle = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(39.4931008, -87.3789913)
    let region = CLCircularRegion(center: sparkle, radius: 10, identifier: "Sparkle")
    // 2
    region.notifyOnEntry = region.notifyOnEntry
    region.notifyOnExit = region.notifyOnExit
    return region
}
```

and in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions of AppDelegate

```
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startMonitoringForRegion(regionWithGeotification())
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

EDIT:

Here is my GPX

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gpx version="1.1" creator="Xcode">
<wpt lat="39.4904392" lon="-87.3803517">
    <name>Pawn It</name>
</wpt>
<wpt lat="39.48823178" lon="-87.37907">
    <name>Sparkle</name>
</wpt>
</gpx>
```

I have all of this in my App Delegate, since I want this to always be present for the app.

I have:

```
import CoreLocation

@UIApplicationMain
 class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

  let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Alert, categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startMonitoringForRegion(regionWithGeotification())
```

Comment: Can your app access Location Services at all?

Comment: Yes, I can. Privacy shows the app as having a Geo-Fence even

Comment: Please post your GPX file contents, and some more info on your CLLocationManager (i.e. where it's actually declared, what properties have been set etc.)

Comment: Updated! Thank you for your help

Comment: Your GPX file looks flawed, A) it's missing the </gpx> closing tag, and B) there's no actual movement (both coordinates are the same)

Comment: The first one is lat="39.4904392" lon="-87.3803517" and the second one was lat="39.48823178" lon="-87.37907" which is about .3 miles away.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98281/discussion-between-caseynolan-and-trever).